# JMockit: how to set properties on injectable?

Tags: java, jmockit

Consider the following code:

```
@Tested
CodeToTest codeToTest;

@Injectable
Injected injected;

@Test
public void test() {
  new Expectations() {{ ... }}
  assertThat(codeToTest.memberVariable).isEqualTo("x");
}

//

public class CodeToTest { public CodeToTest(Injected injected) { memberVariable = injected.getProperty("x") } }
```

I want to test CodeToTest.  CodeToTest needs Injected to be injected into it's constructor.  How do I set a property such as injected.setProperty("x") so that it is available for access in CodeToTest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The test at hand should be covering a specific method of `CodeToTest`; the constructor should have its own tests like your test does. So for example, if the constructor is setting a field according to what gets passed in, like this:

```
public class Bar {
    public int getValue() {
        return 8675309;
    }
}

public class Foo {
    public String field = null;

    public Foo(Bar b) {
        this.field = "" + b.getValue();
    }

    public String getField() {
        return this.field;
    }

    public char getFirstChar() {
        return getField().charAt(0);
    }
}
```

Here I am setting a `String` field according to an `int` found in a `Bar` that was passed into the constructor. I wish to unit test my `getFirstChar()` method ...

```
@Tested Foo foo;

@Injectable Bar bar;

@Test
public void test() throws Exception {
// ...
}
```

Now, as you point out, in this case my `field` has already been set before `test()` even starts. So I have two choices here: Firstly, since I am pulling out the `field` based on its getter, I can partially mock my class being tested:

```
@Test
public void test() throws Exception {
    new Expectations(foo) {{
        foo.getField(); result = "24601";
    }};

    char c = foo.getFirstChar();

    assertThat(c, is('2'));
}
```

OR, if you don't want to do this or if you are doing direct field access rather than via getter, you can use `Deencapsulation` (part of JMockit) to set the internal field and then test:

```
@Test
public void test() throws Exception {
    Deencapsulation.setField(foo, "field", "24601");

    char c = foo.getFirstChar();

    assertThat(c, is('2'));
}
```

And of course, I test my constructor separately:

```
@Test
public void testConstructor() throws Exception {
    new Expectations() {{
        bar.getValue(); result = 24601;
    }};

    Foo foo2 = new Foo(bar);
    String fieldValue = foo2.getField(); // or use Deencapsulation
    assertThat(fieldValue, is("24601"));
}
```

Hope this helps, and good luck!

Comment: This doesn't work for me: my CodeToTest constructor relies on a property being set on the injected object in order to instantiate without error.  @Tested objects are instantiated before the Expectation block is ever met.  (as an aside I have read the documentation but find it wanting in many regards)

Comment: I think basically I can't use Tested and Injectable in this situation, and that I need to just manually construct my object under test

Comment: I'm sorry I misunderstood your initial question ... The unit test should only be testing the method at hand. Your constructor should have its own unit test, and the method at hand  (`CodeToTest.getMemberVariable()` or whatever) should have its own test... And yes, any fields that are set in the constructor should probably be injected with `Deencapsulation`. Let me update my answer with some illustrations...

Comment: Ok, I've updated my answer - got a bit long but hope it is helpful.